# image_to_function in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this method on rails so that I have an image calling a javascript function

```
def image_to_function(name, function, html_options = {})
  html_options.symbolize_keys!
  tag(:input, html_options.merge({ 
      :type => "image", :src => image_path(name),
      :onclick => (html_options[:onclick] ? "#{html_options[:onclick]}; " : "") + "#{function};" 
      }))
end
```

I grabbed this code from the [application helper](http://redmine.rubyforge.org/svn/branches/0.6-stable/app/helpers/application_helper.rb) of the redmine source code, the problem I'm having is that when I click on the image it's sending a POST, does some one know how can I stop that?

This is how I'm using it

```
<%= image_to_function "eliminar-icon.png", "mark_for_destroy(this, '.task')" %>
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: I have solved my problem, the thing is that I didn't use the image_to_function method and I don't know if it was the best way to do it


<%= link_to_function(image_tag("eliminar-icon.png"), "if (confirm('Really?'))
          mark_for_destroy(this, '.task')") %>

Comment: Why not use the `:confirm` option built into Rails' link_to helpers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `onclick` event returns true, your browser follows the href, if it returns false, your browser won't follow. So here's the trick:

```
def image_to_function(name, function, html_options = {})
  html_options.symbolize_keys!
  tag(:input, html_options.merge({ 
      :type => "image", :src => image_path(name),
      :onclick => (html_options[:onclick] ? "#{html_options[:onclick]}; " : "") + "#{function}; return false;" 
      }))
end
```

Alternatively let `#{function}` return true or false and insert the `return` statement in front of the interpolation. This way the called function could control if the browser should follow the href.

PS: You probably want to replace `tag(:input...` with a `link_to_function(image_path(name), ...` construct so you can use it outside of forms, too.